# Creating a function that derives the function `Log[x]`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I want to create a function that derives (`Derivada`) the function `Log[x]` for any base.

My code:

```
Derivada[x_^n_, x_Symbol] /; FreeQ[n, x] := n*x^(n - 1)
Derivada[n_*x_, x_Symbol] /; FreeQ[n, x] := n
Derivada[Log[a_: E, x_], x_Symbol] := 1/(x*Log[a])
Derivada[f_, x_Symbol] /; FreeQ[f, x] := 0
Derivada[(a_?NumericQ) f_, x_Symbol] := a*Derivada[f, x]
Derivada[Exp[x_], x_Symbol] := Exp[x]
Derivada[a_^x_, x_Symbol] := a^x Log[a]
Derivada[u_Plus, x_Symbol] := Derivada[#, x] & /@ u
Derivada[u_*v_, x_Symbol] := u Derivada[v, x] + v Derivada[u, x]
Derivada[u_/v_, x_Symbol] := (Derivada[u, x]*v - u*Derivada[v, x])/v^2
```

My problem is to derive `Log[x]`.
The functions works for any base `Log[2,x]`, `Log[3,x]` except when I use just `Log[x]`.

Doesn't work:

```
In[64]:= Derivada[Log[x], x]

Out[64]= Derivada[Log[x], x]
```

Works:

```
In[65]:= Derivada[Log[2, x], x]

Out[65]= 1/(x Log[2])
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `D`?

Comment: Yes.. I want to create my own function "`D`". Is just for exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the rule

```
Derivada[Log[x_], x_Symbol] := 1/x
```

Since `Log[x]` has only one argument, it cannot match with the pattern `Derivada[Log[a_: E, x_]` - even if the first argument is optional:

```
MatchQ[Log[a_: E, x_], Log[x]]
```

> False